# ElasticSearch index and search analyzers together

Tags: search, elasticsearch, full-text-search

I just reviewed this video - https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7FLXjgB0PQI and got one question about ElasticSearch analyzers.
I've read official documentation and few other articles about analysis and analyzers and I'm confused a bit.

For example I have the following index configuration:

```
"settings" : {
    "analysis" : {      
      "filter" : {
        "autocomplete" : {
          "type" : "edge_ngram",
          "min_gram" : 1,
          "max_gram" : 20
        }
      },
      "analyzer" : {
        "autocomplete" : {
          "type" : "custom",
          "tokenizer" : "standard",
          "filter" : ["lowercase", "autocomplete"]
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "mappings" : {
    "user" : {
      "properties" : {
        "name" : {
          "type" : "multi_field",
          "fields" : {
            "name" : {
              "type" : "string",
              "analyzer" : "standard"
            },
            "autocomplete" : {
              "type" : "string",
              "index_analyzer" : "autocomplete",
              "search_analyzer" : "standard"
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
```

Then I do following search request separately:

```
{
  "match" : {
    "name.autocomplete" : "john smi"
  }
}
```

and this:

```
{
  "match" : {
    "name" : "john smi"
  }
}
```

If I understood correctly I had to see the same result because in both cases ES should use standard analyzer, but I got different results. Why?

**UPDATE**

I have following collection of names in the index: "john smith", "johnathan smith".

Answer (score 0):

I get the same results when I try what you have here, with the required "wrapping". So first I created an index:

```
curl -XPOST "http://localhost:9200/test_index/" -d'
{
   "settings": {
      "analysis": {
         "filter": {
            "autocomplete": {
               "type": "edge_ngram",
               "min_gram": 1,
               "max_gram": 20
            }
         },
         "analyzer": {
            "autocomplete": {
               "type": "custom",
               "tokenizer": "standard",
               "filter": [
                  "lowercase",
                  "autocomplete"
               ]
            }
         }
      }
   },
   "mappings": {
      "user": {
         "properties": {
            "name": {
               "type": "multi_field",
               "fields": {
                  "name": {
                     "type": "string",
                     "analyzer": "standard"
                  },
                  "autocomplete": {
                     "type": "string",
                     "index_analyzer": "autocomplete",
                     "search_analyzer": "standard"
                  }
               }
            }
         }
      }
   }
}'
```

Then add a document:

```
curl -XPUT "http://localhost:9200/test_index/user/1" -d'
{
    "name": "John Smith"
}'
```

The first search yields the document:

```
curl -XPOST "http://localhost:9200/test_index/user/_search" -d'
{
   "query": {
      "match": {
         "name.autocomplete": "john smith"
      }
   }
}'
...
{
   "took": 1,
   "timed_out": false,
   "_shards": {
      "total": 5,
      "successful": 5,
      "failed": 0
   },
   "hits": {
      "total": 1,
      "max_score": 0.2712221,
      "hits": [
         {
            "_index": "test_index",
            "_type": "user",
            "_id": "1",
            "_score": 0.2712221,
            "_source": {
               "name": "John Smith"
            }
         }
      ]
   }
}
```

and so does the second:

```
curl -XPOST "http://localhost:9200/test_index/user/_search" -d'
{
   "query": {
      "match": {
         "name": "john smith"
      }
   }
}'
...
{
   "took": 1,
   "timed_out": false,
   "_shards": {
      "total": 5,
      "successful": 5,
      "failed": 0
   },
   "hits": {
      "total": 1,
      "max_score": 0.2712221,
      "hits": [
         {
            "_index": "test_index",
            "_type": "user",
            "_id": "1",
            "_score": 0.2712221,
            "_source": {
               "name": "John Smith"
            }
         }
      ]
   }
}
```

Is there something else about your set-up that is different from what I did here?

Here is the code I used for this problem:

http://sense.qbox.io/gist/4c8299be570c87f1179f70bfd780a7e9f8d40919

Comment: I've updated the code here (input names and queries examples) http://sense.qbox.io/gist/4c8299be570c87f1179f70bfd780a7e9f8d40919. Please check.

Comment: You will have to save your changes an give me the new link for me to be able to see them. Make your changes and hit the "save code" button in the upper right, and you will be redirected to a new url. Paste that url here so I can see what you did (the one you gave me is the same one I gave you, so I don't see your changes).